# SQL Query com múltiplos argumentos

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou precisando criar uma consulta SQL que pode ou não ter vários argumentos. Exemplo:

```
Pesquisa 1: "João Goiânia"
Pesquisa 2: "Goiânia João"
Pesquisa 3: "João Advogado Goiânia"
```

A query deverá percorrer três campos: nome, cidade, profissão. Sendo que os argumentos podem estar em um, dois ou em todos eles.

Imaginando uma tabela populada:

```
id, nome, cidade, profissão
1, Maria, Brasília, Advogado
2, José, Anápolis, Engenheiro
3, João Carlos, Goiânia, Advogado Trabalhista
4, João da Silva, Goiânia, Médico
```

O resultado para a pesquisa 1 e 2 seriam os registros 3 e 4, e para a pesquisa 3 seria apenas o registro 3.

Pensei em utilizar `campo IN (arg1, arg2, arg3)`, porém existe a possibilidade de o argumento não estar completo, como no exemplo. Qual a melhor solução?

> O meu banco é: PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: Qual é o seu banco? MySQL, SQL Server, Firebird....

Comment: uma vez que você não sabe quantos campos nem a ordem, uma opção seria criar um índice *full text'

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: @RicardoPontual estou lendo sobre sua sugestão, e realmente a busca textual me parece ser uma boa solução. Assim que encontrar um artigo bom e completo sobre o assunto posto aqui.

Comment: Siml para o `postgresql` acredito que seja. Aqui uma boa leitura: [full text](https://pt.slideshare.net/spjuliano/fts-26392077)

Answer (score 1):

Se for SQL SERVER, poderá ser feito assim:

```
SELECT * FROM NOME_DA_TABELA WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(NOME))+LTRIM(RTRIM(CIDADE))+LTRIM(RTRIM(PROFISSÃO)) LIKE '%JoãoGoiânia%'

SELECT * FROM NOME_DA_TABELA WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(NOME))+LTRIM(RTRIM(CIDADE))+LTRIM(RTRIM(PROFISSÃO)) LIKE '%JoãoGoiâniaAdvogado%'
```

Concateno as colunas, tiro os espaços e uso o like com dois %, um no inicio e um no fim. AI basta pesquisar com os filtros que você quiser, porém sem nenhum espaço e na ordem que você ordenou na cláusula WHERE

Comment: Resposta boa, mas ao invés de usar `LTRIM(RTRIM(ID))` não seria interessante usar apenas `TRIM(ID)`? Este comando já tira os espaços do fim e do inicio de cada string, assim ficaria mais clean o script :D

Comment: Eu pensei em usar o `trim`, porém aqui estava dando esse erro: http://prntscr.com/kp7wgb Por isso usei o `ltrim(rtrim(' '))`

Comment: Entendo, provavelmente é a versão do seu banco [Aqui funciona certinho](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7d02b/4)

Comment: O problema que vejo de concatenar é quando um dos argumentos não é completo, como no meu exemplo, o nome da tabela é João Carlos e o usuário informou apenas João. Ainda tem a profissão e a cidade que pode acontecer a mesma coisa.

Comment: É... esse é um problema mesmo... xover se consigo pensar em algo

Comment: Se fosse `sql-server`, seria melhor usar o `CONTAINS`...